# Karma Undefined is not an object when using nested object notation

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am getting the following error when running my Karma Unit Tests:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'vm.device.name')
```

vm.device.name is being set within my controller. When I change the name to vm.deviceName it works flawlessly.

Why does it fail when I use this nested notation but it works fine without it?

Comment: Can you include the code in your controller that sets the value? Are you sure that `vm.device` is defined?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewEisenberg! You were right I just needed to add vm.device = {} in my beforeEach statement and it fixed the issue.